# Postgres combining date and time fields, is this efficient

Tags: postgresql

I am selecting rows based on a date range which is held in a string using the below SQL which works but is this a efficient way of doing it.  As you can see the date and time is held in different fields.  From my memory or doing Oracle work as soon as you put a function around a attribute it cant use indexes.

```
select  *
from    events 
where   venue_id = '2'
and     EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (start_date + start_time)) 
between EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2017-09-01 00:00')::timestamp) 
and     EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2017-09-30 00:00')::timestamp)
```

So is there a way of doing this that can use indexes?

Comment: Why extract epoch? Why not just do `start_date + start_time BETWEEN '2017-09-01 00:00'::timestamp AND '2017-09-30 00:00'::timestamp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Preface: Since your query is limited to a single `venue_id`, both examples below create a compound index with `venue_id` first.*

If you want an index for improving *that* query, you can create an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html):

```sql
CREATE INDEX events_start_idx
ON events (venue_id, (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (start_date + start_time))));
```

If you don't want a dedicated function index, you can create a normal index on the `start_date` column, and add extra logic to use the index. The index will then limit access plan to date range, and fringe records with wrong time of day on first and last dates are filtered out.

In the following, I'm also eliminating the unnecessary extraction of epoch.

```sql
CREATE INDEX events_venue_start
ON events (venue_id, start_date);
```

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    events
WHERE   venue_id = '2'
AND     start_date BETWEEN '2017-09-01'::date AND '2017-09-30'::date
AND     start_date + start_time BETWEEN '2017-09-01 00:00'::timestamp
                                    AND '2017-09-30 00:00'::timestamp
```

The first two parts of the `WHERE` clause will use the index to full benefit. the last part is then use the filter the records found by the index.

Comment: Is 'start_date BETWEEN '2017-09-01'::date AND '2017-09-30'::date' actually needed?

Comment: @BenEdwards Yes, otherwise it cannot use the index fully.